# PHP asynchronous reading (shell scripting)

Tags: php, shell, pipe

I have a PHP TCP daemon which provides data to clients. One of the features is to get info from "tail -f messages" command. So I have to run this command asynchronously and in case of new data, send it to the clients.

I have a problem how to create this asynchronous reader - when new data is added, run the method, otherwise do the other things you have to.

Mejmo

EDIT: My problem could be resolved by using some kinds of threads and IPC (does php support threads?).

Answer (score 1):

If you can install extensions, you can implement this using the libevent PHP extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use [popen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to execute `tail -f message`, passing `'r'` as the `$mode` parameter. Then you can [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) from the returned file pointer.

Comment: No, this approach is blocking the script.

Answer (score -1):

Try [`stream_set_blocking()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php), it should do the trick.